# C++ - How to template a class attribute and not the functions of the class?

Tags: c++, class, templates

I would like to template an attribute of a class, but not all the functions.

```
enum myEnum
{
CHAR,
INT,
FLOAT,
DOUBLE
};

class   myClass
{
public:
  myClass(T);
  ~myClass();
  myEnum getType(); // need to template it to know the type
  myClass *operator+(const myClass&);
   /*
I don't want to template it, because I don't need it,
I can find the type tanks to getType() (for the precision of the operation,
I'll need it, ie. for a char + int)
*/
protected:
  T _value;
  std::string _sValue;
};
```

I know how to template a unique function in a class, I just have to write `template<typename T>` above the function in the class. I want to know how can I template the attribute `T _value` without templating all the class.

If I try to do the same for an attribute, I mean :

```
template<typename T>
T _value;
```

I have that errors:
`error: data member '_value' cannot be a member template`
`error: ‘myClass’ is not a template`

Comment: Why the down votes? Granted, it can be made clearer, but still a question others can benefit from.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need a template data member, then your class *has* to be a class template:

```
enum myenum { .... };

template <typename T>
class myclass {
 public:
  myenum gettype() const;
  myclass& operator+=(const myclass& rhs);
 private:
  T value_;
};
```

Comment: No an enum type, I didn't write it here, but I need it to be templated in fact to know the type, I'll add the enum to my post.

Comment: @Elfayer and how is the `enum` related to the templating? Do you want to have many different enum types?

Comment: This is just an example. I don't want to template the whole class, because I don't want to template all the functions of the class. But I don't know how to do it, because I have a templated attribute which required the class to be templated. Or I don't know how to do it, that's why I ask.

Comment: @Elfayer as I said in my answer, your class *has* to be a template. There's no way around that.

Comment: So what can I do for the `operator+` function ? I'll have to pass it a type anyway?

Comment: @Elfayer, why must the attribute be templated?

Comment: Because I want to use my `operator+` for any type, so that I can add a char to an int.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is very unclear as to what you want, but I'm guessing it may be something like this:

```
template<typename T>
T getType();


template<typename T>
T myClass::getType()
{
   T t;
   return t;
}
```

If you want a templated member in your class, you have to make the class itself a template.  There's really no other way.